# Google Sheets IF THIS AND ELSE OR

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm having some issues trying to accomplish the below in a google sheet.
What I'd like to have happened is:

```
IF Cell O1 has a value of "Yes" AND Cell E1 is <= 25,000 
Cell P1 = "DEFM-HW-A"

OR Cell O1 has a value of "Yes" AND Cell E1 is > 25,000 
Cell P1 = "DEFM-HW-B"

OR IF O1 = "No"
Cell P1 = "No"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in P1:

```
=IF(O1="Yes",IF(E1<=25000,"DEFM-HW-A","DEFM-HW-B"),"No")
```